# Set Ros2 Parameter from another Node

Tags: c++, parameters, ros2

I have two nodes in c++ that use the same parameter.
If I want to reconfigure the node1 parameter_x via the rqt, it would be great if the parameter_x of the node2 is also changed automatically.
Is there a possibility for this?

i have try in node1:

```
auto node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("node2");
node->set_parameter(rclcpp::Parameter("parameter_x", 50));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution:

```
auto parameter = rcl_interfaces::msg::Parameter();
auto request = std::make_shared<rcl_interfaces::srv::SetParametersAtomically::Request>();

client = this->create_client<rcl_interfaces::srv::SetParametersAtomically>(serviceName); // E.g.: serviceName = "/turtlesim/set_parameters_atomically"

parameter.name = parameter_name;  // E.g.: parameter_name = "background_b"
parameter.value.type = 1          //  bool = 1,    int = 2,        float = 3,     string = 4
parameter.value.bool_value = true // .bool_value, .integer_value, .double_value, .string_value

request->parameters.push_back(parameter);

while (!client->wait_for_service(1s)) {
    if (!rclcpp::ok()) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "Interrupted while waiting for the service. Exiting.");
    return;
    }
    RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(this->get_logger(), "service " << serviceName <<" not available, waiting again..."); 
}
auto result = client->async_send_request(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done using set_parameters inside of nodes but instead using a **Service call** . Two service calls are availble

- [SetParameters](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters.html)
  allows setting parameters one at a time
- [SetParametersAtomically](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParametersAtomically.html)
  sets multiple parameters at once, atomically. This means that if setting one parameter fails, none of the parameters are changed.
- I have produced a video about it as well -> [link](https://youtu.be/Qw9RR1jShYQ)